# How to send emails using nodemailer and roundcube

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer, roundcube

What I'm trying to do is send emails through the `nodemailer` library. I believe that the problem is time to configure the host. I tried using gmail and it works perfectly, but when I use my own email provider and it returns this error below.

***User authentication failedError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http://myserver.com"***

```
module.exports = {
    host: 'http://myserver.com',
    port: '587',
    user: 'email@myserver.com',
    pass: 'mypassword'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete the protocol `http://` from host variable. You trying to do dns request to `http://myserver.com`, not `myserver.com`.

Also, the mail services use not `http` protocol, but `smtp` (`smtps` for secure connections).

Another way: you can use one-line connection string

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(
`smtp://email:mypassword@myserver.com:587`);
```

Answer (score 0):

The server you've listed isn't a valid domain - i.e if I run a DNS lookup it won't resolve to anything.

This suggests to me that you are trying to connect to a mail server on your local network and have changed the DNS in your router or your machine's hosts file to map a local IP to a named domain. If this is the case I'd suggest getting the actual IP address of your local mail server and use this instead and see if this helps connectivity.

Comment: My DNS server is valid